# Does the Entity Framework use a default intital catalog and what assumptions does it make?

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I did (pretty much) everything correct in a new EF project, but I forgot to use the named connection string in the EF context class, so, it used the default.

It created a new database inside the SQL Express default data directory, and it worked perfectly.

When I realised my mistake (After wondering for ages why no files were showing up in the app_data folder), I renamed the class to use the named connection string and then I kept getting the following error:

> Unable to complete operation. The
>   supplied SqlConnection does not
>   specify an initial catalog.

I know how to fix this, but, EF is like magic to me! I can't believe it works as well as it does and I am just curious as to what it uses by default / is there a list anywhere of "assumptions" that EF uses on your behalf if you specify nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it uses database with the same name as your context but once you specify custom named connection string you must provide the name of used database either by `Initial Catalog` or `Database` parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but I figured it out by changing the `web.conf`. You need to specify an initial catalog and Integrated security and make a user instance.

Here is working web.conf:

```
add name="MovieDBContext"
   connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Movies.mdf;Initial Catalog=Movies;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Instance=true"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```